# find last paragraph of each section from a book

Tags: python, regex, paragraph

I have a text file including a book and I need last paragraph of each section.

I can find first paragraph of each section. I used regex..I tried to change my code but I couldn't achieve. Can you give me any idea about to reach last paragraph of each section?

Here is my code that finds first paragraphs

```
print("\nFIRST PARAGRAPH OF EACH SECTION\n")
    with open(fileName) as fi:
        data = fi.read()

    #line of Roman numeral characters
    #line without lower case characters ( titles )
    #find first paragraph

    paras = re.findall(r"""
                       [IVXLCDM]+\n\n   
                       [^a-z]+\n\n
                       ((?:[^\n][\n]?)+)
                       """, data, re.VERBOSE)
    print ("\n\n".join(paras))
```

A part of book is given.

```
XVIII

THE MORALS OF WILD ANIMALS


The ethics and morals of men and animals are thoroughly
comparative, and it is only by direct comparisons that they can be
analyzed and classified. It is quite possible that there are quite
a number of intelligent men and women who are not yet aware of the
fact that wild animals _have_ moral codes, and that on an
average they live up to them better than men do to theirs.

.............(here is the body part of section)

Only two wild animal species known to me,--wolves and crocodiles,
--devour their own kind; but many of the races of men have been
cannibals, and some are so today.


XIX


THE LAWS OF THE FLOCKS AND THE HERDS

I approach this subject with a
feeling of satisfaction; but I would not like to state the
number of hours that I have spent in watching the play of our
wild animals.

.............(here is the body part of section)

In playing, young chimps, orangs or monkeys seize each other and
wrestle, fall, and roll over and over, indefinitely. They make
great pretenses of biting each other, but it is all make-believe.
My favorite orang-utan pet in Borneo loved to play at biting me,
but whenever the pressure became too strong I would say chidingly,
"Ah! Ah!" and his jaws would instantly relax. He loved to butt me
in the chest with his head, make wry faces, and make funny noises
with his lips. I tried to teach him "cat's cradle" but it was too
much for him. His clumsy fingers could not manage it.
```

**Output should be like this:**

```
Only two wild animal species known to me,--wolves and crocodiles,
--devour their own kind; but many of the races of men have been
cannibals, and some are so today.

In playing, young chimps, orangs or monkeys seize each other and
wrestle, fall, and roll over and over, indefinitely. They make
great pretenses of biting each other, but it is all make-believe.
My favorite orang-utan pet in Borneo loved to play at biting me,
but whenever the pressure became too strong I would say chidingly,
"Ah! Ah!" and his jaws would instantly relax. He loved to butt me
in the chest with his head, make wry faces, and make funny noises
with his lips. I tried to teach him "cat's cradle" but it was too
much for him. His clumsy fingers could not manage it.
```

Comment: I don't know python, but maybe this regex can help you `\n([^\n]*)\n(?=\n[IVXLCDM]*\n|$)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) and [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) without a complex regex:

```
with open(fileName) as fi:
    data = fi.read()

l = [i.strip() for i in re.split('[IVXLCDM]+\n\n', text) if i.strip()]
for i in l:
    print(i.split('\n\n')[-1])
    print('\n')
```

Demo:

```
Only two wild animal species known to me,--wolves and crocodiles,
--devour their own kind; but many of the races of men have been
cannibals, and some are so today.


In playing, young chimps, orangs or monkeys seize each other and
wrestle, fall, and roll over and over, indefinitely. They make
great pretenses of biting each other, but it is all make-believe.
My favorite orang-utan pet in Borneo loved to play at biting me,
but whenever the pressure became too strong I would say chidingly,
"Ah! Ah!" and his jaws would instantly relax. He loved to butt me
in the chest with his head, make wry faces, and make funny noises
with his lips. I tried to teach him "cat's cradle" but it was too
much for him. His clumsy fingers could not manage it.
```